# Webpack "npm run build" doesn't work on Google Cloud, but works in local machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine, webpack

I've been using Google Cloud App Engine, everything has been working perfectly until recently.

I've a React Application that I use webpack to bundle together. Whenever I run the production webpack file on my local machine it works fine, but whenever I run it on Google  Cloud App Engine, it gets stuck here [clean-webpack-plugin: /home/luis/projectname/dist has been removed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY6dd.png)

It's worked fine before, the only things that have changed are that I've added a custom domain, and ssl through let's encrypt. Currently there are two instances through GAE running the previous version of the site(I need to update it)

I've tried creating a new project, and repeating the process from scratch the issue persists.

edit:

- Here's the package.json

  `{
    "name": "roto-hive",
    "version": "0.5.0",
    "engines": {
      "node": "8.11.3"
    },
    "description": "RotoHive Web Application",
    "main": "index.js",
    "directories": {
      "test": "test"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
      "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
      "express": "^4.16.3",
      "fantasydata-node-client": "^1.1.0",
      "firebase": "^5.0.4",
      "firebase-admin": "^5.12.1",
      "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
      "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
      "mobx": "^5.0.2",
      "mobx-react": "^5.2.3",
      "moment": "^2.22.2",
      "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
      "react": "^16.4.1",
      "react-beautiful-dnd": "^7.1.3",
      "react-circular-progressbar": "^0.8.0",
      "react-cookie-consent": "^1.7.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
      "react-firebaseui": "^3.0.4",
      "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
      "react-image": "^1.3.1",
      "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.2",
      "react-recaptcha": "^2.3.8",
      "react-responsive-modal": "^3.0.3",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
      "react-select": "^1.2.1",
      "react-spinkit": "^3.0.0",
      "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
      "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
      "solc": "^0.4.24",
      "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.5",
      "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
      "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "assert": "^1.4.1",
      "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
      "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
      "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
      "chai": "^4.1.2",
      "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
      "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.11",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
      "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
      "eslint": "^4.19.1",
      "eslint-config-standard": "^11.0.0",
      "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
      "eslint-plugin-node": "^6.0.1",
      "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.9.1",
      "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
      "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
      "ganache-cli": "^6.1.3",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
      "jshint": "^2.9.6",
      "lodash": "^4.17.10",
      "mocha": "^5.2.0",
      "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
      "prettier-eslint": "^8.8.1",
      "purecss": "^1.0.0",
      "react-particles-js": "^2.2.0",
      "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
      "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
      "webpack": "^4.14.0",
      "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
      "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
      "start": "node ./dist/server.js",
      "clean": "rm -rf dist node_modules build",
      "watch": "webpack --watch --config webpack.dev.js",
      "test": "mocha",
      "start:dev": "npm run build && nodemon ./dist/server.js"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://LDLugo@bitbucket.org/LDLugo/rotohive.git"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/LDLugo/rotohive#readme"
  }`
- Here's the webpack.prod.js

`

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

const modeObj = 'production'
const moduleObj = {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: 'babel-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader' },
        { loader: 'css-loader' }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: [
        'file-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
      use: [
        'file-loader'
      ]
    }
  ]
}

const client = {
  entry: {
    'client': './src/client/index.js'
  },
  mode: modeObj,
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public')
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: moduleObj,
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.html',
      favicon: 'public/favicon.ico'
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: true
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  }
}

const server = {
  entry: {
    'server': './src/server/index.js'
  },
  mode: modeObj,
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  },
  module: moduleObj,
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
}

module.exports = [client, server]
```

edit: 
So I bundled the code into a dist folder and tried manually deploying it. GAE spit out this err: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE (as well as other stuff, but that one stuck out to me)

All other

Comment: Can you share your package.json and other config files if any ?

Comment: I've added them now, let me know if you'd need anything else

Comment: I ran the same command in heroku and it too said 'process exited'

Comment: Could you please provide the full error output and try deploying with verbosity set to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I wasn't able to solve that issue(I managed to temporarily solved it but it always came back). I did find a work around.

So what I did was download the google sdk on my local machine, and then connected it to my google cloud account(the one that I created the project in). Then deployed it from my local machine.

So I was able to build with `npm run build` and then used `gcloud app deploy` to deploy the bundled code.